# How does display (LCD/LED) connects to system bus?

Tags: motherboard, gpu, lcd, led, bus

The problem arose for me when I realized that the Laptops/PCs use two GPUs (one of them is an On-Chip low-performance and the other is an external high-performance GPU), and switch between these two on demand. So how is this possible? AFAIK displays connect directly to the video cards (of course GPUs today) and I remember this from my old PC system which the GPU has a VGA port itself.

So if the display connects to motherboard instead of GPU directly, which technology does it use to talk to GPUs?

Comment: Your thinking too closed minded... the monitor doesn't connect directly to the GPUs when there are multiple ones, it connects to a display controller, all the graphics "work" is done by either the low power or the high performance GPU and sent to the display controller to put on the screen. The CPU and software decide which GPU does the work for which application. In theory you could have several GPU's each doing specific work for a certain application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the display controller is something like a framebuffer (I mean the GPU calculated pixels will be send to it to be stored and display just like framebuffer)? Which bus technology does the displays controller use (SATA, PCIe, USB, ...) ?

Comment: I don't understand the technical details of it, never felt a need to know since it's all built into the motherboard, sorry.

Comment: *"Which bus technology does the displays controller use"* -- Look at the "input signals"column of http://www.digitalview.com/products/lcd-controllers-home  An integrated, single-board solution would dispense with the high-level interface, and probably interface the frame buffer more directly with the LCD controller.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the reply. what you linked above is about display side of the whole story i.e. the LCD controller inside a monitor (display) , isn't it? However what I'm talking about, is the PC side. I've understood that there is a display interface (controller) inside the GPU/Motherboard. But how do this controller connects to system bus? Take a look at http://www.laptopschematic.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/acer-Aspire-9110-Block-Diagram.jpg and http://cdn.overclock.net/8/89/500x1000px-LL-894e7734_MSI_Z270_GAMING_M7_block.jpeg

Comment: Finally I was looking for something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Digital_Video_Out